# IMAP x Gmail => labels?

Tags: gmail, label, imap

Any experiences on a way to get gmail labels (or even filters ?) from an imap connection ?
Can't find a clue... thx for any infos about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a IMAP proxy ([Net::Gmail::IMAP::Label](https://github.com/zmughal/gmail-imap-label)) that filters the connection and adds the Gmail labels to the mail headers under X-Label. If your client can display that field next to the subject, it will look similar to the Gmail web interface.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, if you are using IMAP programmatically, you can use the gmail imap extensions to access this information:

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/#x-gm-labels

```
a010 FETCH 1:4 (X-GM-LABELS)
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Inbox \Sent Important "Muy Importante"))
* 2 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (foo))
* 3 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ())
* 4 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Drafts))
a010 OK FETCH (Success)
```

Just to add to this, if you are using JavaMail, with 1.5.1, they have some support for these gmail extensions:
https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html

Answer (score 6):

Labels can be seen as IMAP folders.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this. You need to [enable IMAP](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/fwdandpop) of course, obviously - you then need to configure [labels on a per-label basis](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/labels) to select 'imap' for the ones that you want to export. If you don't, then you'll just get the default ones, like INBOX and All Mail.

Answer (score 1):

There is definetly no way to get Gmail filter-rules from IMAP. But Gmail has an import/export feature for that.

Labels can be seen as IMAP folders. The latest thunderbird release does that in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail labels appear is folders in IMAP. If you can get a list of the folders that a message appears in, you can infer what the labels are.