# gmail labels mapped to outlook categories not folders

Tags: outlook, gmail, outlook-addin, categories, label

What is the easiest way to map Outlook Categories to Gmail Labels?

I don't like how when I use Gmail with IMAP in Outlook that I get folders for each Gmail Label, I want to have Outlook Categories.

I don't mind having to use a paid addon or doing some VBA.

Searching has turned up nothing, except this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573148/4599373 which is an IMAP proxy which maps Gmail Labels into x-labels which might work in Outlook.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get this working by any chance?

Comment: No I did not :(

Comment: I'm presently trying a different method - I've stopped Gmail from making labels available as IMAP folders, and I'm using Outlook's rules to apply categories instead of Gmail's for labels. Though of course, no sync.